# ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException in onNotificationPosted method

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

After upgrading targert android version to 33 on firebase crashes appeared regarding ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException. Does anyone know how to solve them, below I send a piece of code related to the Music service. I am using exoplayer 2.18.1.

```
            override fun onNotificationPosted(
                notificationId: Int,
                notification: Notification,
                ongoing: Boolean
            ) {
                if (ongoing && !isForegroundService) {
                    playerNotification = notification
                    startForeground(notificationId, notification)
                    isForegroundService = true
                } else if (!ongoing) {
                    stopForeground(true)
                    isForegroundService = false
                }
            }

            override fun onNotificationCancelled(notificationId: Int, dismissedByUser: Boolean) {
                stopForeground(true)
                isForegroundService = false
                stopSelf()
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

I Want to reduce the errors associated with using the music service

Answer (score 1):

The `ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException` is thrown when an app tries to start a foreground service without meeting the necessary conditions. Starting from Android 12 (API level 33), there are stricter conditions for starting foreground services.

Here are the steps to resolve the issue:

1. **Use `Service.startForeground()` Immediately**: When starting a foreground service, you should call `startForeground()` immediately after the service starts. Any delay can cause the system to kill your service or throw the `ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException`.
2. **Use `Context.startForegroundService()`**: When starting the service, use `Context.startForegroundService()` instead of `Context.startService()`. This indicates to the system that you intend to make the service a foreground service.
3. **Handle Service Lifecycle Properly**: Ensure that you handle the service's lifecycle methods properly. For instance, if the service is no longer needed, call `stopSelf()` to stop the service.
4. **Update the Notification**: If you're using ExoPlayer's `PlayerNotificationManager`, ensure that you're updating the notification when there are changes in playback state or metadata. This will ensure that the notification remains accurate and the service remains in the foreground.
5. **Check for Pending Intents**: Ensure that the notification you're using for the foreground service has a pending intent so that users can return to the app from the notification.

Given the code you provided, here's an updated version that should help reduce the errors:

```kotlin
private fun createNotificationListener(): PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener {
    return object : PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener {

        override fun onNotificationPosted(
            notificationId: Int,
            notification: Notification,
            ongoing: Boolean
        ) {
            if (ongoing && !isForegroundService) {
                playerNotification = notification
                // Ensure you're calling startForeground immediately after starting the service
                startForeground(notificationId, notification)
                isForegroundService = true
            } else if (!ongoing) {
                // Handle the case where the notification is no longer ongoing
                stopForeground(false)
                isForegroundService = false
            }
        }

        override fun onNotificationCancelled(notificationId: Int, dismissedByUser: Boolean) {
            stopForeground(true) // Consider using true to remove the notification
            isForegroundService = false
            stopSelf()
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, ensure that you have the necessary permissions in your manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

And when starting the service:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(context, YourMusicService::class.java)
context.startForegroundService(intent)
```

By following these steps and ensuring that you're adhering to the foreground service best practices, you should be able to reduce the errors associated with using the music service on Android 12 and above.

Comment: same error is coming even after following the step that you mentioned. Is there any way to check weather it is right time to launch service from background to avoid ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.